# Ubuntu install showing as Zesty when I was on Yakkety and I'm having software problems

Tags: apt, repository, versions

[image: Photo showing it's Zesty and the issue I am having]

I can't even open the Software and Sources program too. All I did was

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

then rebooted and now all of a sudden I'm on Zesty and some things aren't working. I'm also having trouble installing the proprietary Nvidia drivers too.

I have also done this but it didn't work:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall base-files
```

Comment: I have also done this but it didn't work λ kevin [~] → sudo apt install --reinstall base-files

Comment: Could you please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter you can either 1) select, copy & paste the terminal content or 2) [save it to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: What's the output of `lsb_relase -a`, `uname -a`, and `apt-cache policy base-files`?

Comment: I'm having the same problem